# Find the index of a sub array that contains a number

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

```
var array = [[2,3,4],[4,5,6],[2,3,9]];
var number = 9;
```

If I have this nested array and this variable how do I return the index
where the sub-array with the number is.  So the final result should be 2 or.

So far I have:

```
var indexOfRemainingArray = array.filter(function(item,i) {
   if(item != number) {
     return i;
   }
});
```

I would like to know how to use map or filter functions for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`Array#findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex?v=control) to find the index, and use [`Array#indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some?v=cont) in the callback to check if the sub array contains the number at least once.

```js
var array = [[2,3,4],[4,5,6],[2,3,9]];
var number = 9;

var indexOfRemainingArray = array.findIndex(function(sub) {
   return sub.indexOf(number) !== -1;
});

console.log(indexOfRemainingArray);
```

And if you need both indexes, you can assign the result of the inner `indexOf` to a variable:

```js
var array = [[2,3,4],[4,5,9],[2,3,1]];
var number = 9;

var innerIndex;
var indexOfRemainingArray = array.findIndex(function(sub) {
   innerIndex = sub.indexOf(number);
   return innerIndex !== -1;
});

console.log(indexOfRemainingArray, innerIndex);
```